# Python: Assigning function along with parameters to a variable

Tags: python

```
def test(name):
    print "name:", name

func = test
func("testing") # it works, as I know that the function test accepts one parameter.
```

My question is, what if "test" has varying number of arguments depending on the scenario and how "func" knows how many number of arguments to pass and what are those arguments name.

Sorry, if I am not clear. This would give more clear picture on the scenario.

I have a function dispatcher.

```
testcase_obj  = testcase() # A object of a class    
if command.startswith("test1"):    
    output = exec_test1()    
elif command.startswith("do_test"):    
    output = exec_do_test(testcase_obj)
```

Now, I want to wrap a function whenever user sends an option while executing the script. I changed above code as:

```
testcase_obj  = testcase() # A object of a class    
if command.startswith("test1"):    
    func = exec_test1() # Mistake, this should be func = exec_test1
elif command.startswith("do_test"):    
    func = exec_do_test(testcase_obj) # I don't know how assign exec_do_test along
                                      # with its parameter to 'func'. I don't want to
                                      # to call exec_to_test.

if option_given:    
    func = wrapper_func(func)    
    output = func() # At this point I don't how many parameters that "func" takes.
```

Comment: You'll need to give more specifics about what you're trying to do.  It doesn't make sense to try to call a "mystery function" without knowing what arguments it accepts.  Even if you can programmatically figure out how many arguments it takes and what their names are, how would you decide what values to pass for them without reading the documentation and knowing what they do?

Comment: Your edited question still doesn't really explain how you hope to make use of the wrapped function.  Do you know what `exec_test1()` and `exec_do_test(testcase_obj)` return?  If you do, then you know what `func` will be in each case, and how many arguments to pass in each case.  If you don't, knowing how many arguments they take won't help you, because you still won't know what values you can meaningfully pass for those arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `inspect` module

```
import inspect
inspect.getargspec(func).args
```

will give:

```
['name']
```

Answer (score 5):

After saying `func = test`, `func` becomes *just another name for `test`*. So, you call `func` exactly the same way as `test`, and if you give `func` the wrong number of arguments you'll get a `TypeError` as if you had called `test` incorrectly.

For more information about the difference between variables in other languages and names in Python, see [Code like a Pythonista](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables).

Comment: If "test" takes variable number of arguments and it is assigned to "func". I want to know how many arguments that "func" has. Introspection(dir(func)) will not show how many arguments that "func" can take.

Comment: Well, `dir(test)` wouldn't tell you either. Remember, they are names for the *same exact thing*. You probably want `help(func)`...

Answer (score 1):

It will be the same.

func is just an alias to test, not a function calling test

Answer (score 1):

> If "test" takes variable number of arguments and it is assigned to
>   "func". I want to know how many arguments that "func" has.
>   Introspection(dir(func)) will not show how many arguments that "func"
>   can take.

`func` is not a function. It is just an alias pointing to the function that is called `test`. So there is no way `func` can take a different number of arguments than `test` because `func` *is not a function, just a name pointing to one*. You can verify this:

```
>>> def test(arg1):
...    print 'test was given ',arg1
...
>>> func = test
>>> test.func_name
'test'
>>> func.func_name
'test'
>>> id(func)
3075004876L
>>> id(test)
3075004876L
>>> inspect.getargspec(func).args
['arg1']
>>> inspect.getargspec(test).args
['arg1']
```

Comment: `func` and `test` are absolutely equivalent. Both are names pointing to a function. So nothing special about `func`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to assign 'test' along with its signature 'arg1' to 'func'? So that if I call func(), it should translate to the call test(arg1)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way if you give default values to your function.

```
def test(name="default",hi=0):
    print "name:", name,hi

func = test
func("testing")
func("testing",6) 
func(0)
```